# SSRS 2008 Permission Issue

Tags: ssrs-2008, access-denied

I've spent almost whole day fixing permission issue on Reporting Server without any success. So would really appreciate any help.

Reporting services were already installed on the pc, but weren't ever used before.
PC is running Win Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1
Pc is not in domain.
SQL is 2008.

In Reporting Service Config Manager I setup account to 'Local System' and tried to access      `http://server/ReportServer` (I tried any different accounts)

And here comes my problem. 
I keep getting error 
**The permissions granted to user 'username' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)**

I'm logged in as admin account. I understand that this is permission issue, but really not sure where can I fix this. 
Also user has db_owner + RSExecRole in ReportServer db

I can access `http://server/Reports`, but don't see site setting link.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found solution that worked for me. I had to edit **RsReportServer.config** file

```
<AuthenticationTypes>
   <RSWindowsNegotiate/>
   <RSWindowsNTLM/>
</AuthenticationTypes>
```

I replaced code above with this

```
<AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsBasic/>
</AuthenticationTypes>
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your user have the lowest permissions basing on what you said that you can go to `http://server/Reports`

but do not see this

[image]

To further see if you really have permission issues you need to use SSMS to open your reporting server instance like such

[image]

If you successfully log in to that instance you should be able to see and manipulate the following roles and what the roles can do

[image]

I suggest giving full access to the **Browser** role and check now if you can get the site settings

Comment: Hi Raymund, I tried as you suggested, but unfortunately didn't work. I ticked all checkboxes. Wouldn't be because only system roles has 'Manager roles' task? If yes, I will need to somehow add user to this role. But problem is how.

Comment: This might give you a clearer picture http://www.sqlmusings.com/2010/08/28/retrieve-ssrs-report-definition-role-assignments-executions-using-t-sql/ the second query there will give you all permission on a folder or report, make sure your user is there first

Comment: Hi Raymund, thanks for help. In may case it turned to by a bit different problem. Please see my answer. Thanks anyway